# does django has a method like 'render_template' in gae (google app engine)

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

This is my gae code:

```
class BaseRequestHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def render_template(self, filename, template_values={}):
        values={
        }
        template_values.update(values)
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates', filename)
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))


class CounterHandler(BaseRequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render_template('counters.html',{'counters': Counter.all()})
```

Does django has this method?
How to make a method like `render_template` in django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's called `render_to_response`, and is explained here:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/